# 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

how can I store `$result` value in a 2d array. here my code-

```
$sql="SELECT a.userId, b.name, b.dob FROM tbltree a INNER JOIN tblprofile b ON a.userId = b.userId WHERE a.superId ='$uid'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$link)or die(mysql_error());
```

2d array having three columns-`userId | name | dob`

Comment: what do you want in each dimension? Can you describe the problem or desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$sql = "..."
$result = mysql_query(...) ...;

$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $result_array[] = $row;
}
```

That will give you:

```
$result_array[0] = array('key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2', ...);
$result_array[1] = array('key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2', ...);
$result_array[2] = etc...
```

If you don't want an associate array for the sub-array, there's other [fetch modes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) as well

Comment: okie, it means if i have to access first row, i can access like `result_array[0][userId] OR result_array[0][name]`. Is it?

Comment: It'd be a regular multidimensional array, which in PHP is just an array of arrays. So... $result_array[1]['key1'] would fetch the value associated with 'key1' from the 2nd entry in the main array. You can add as many dimensions as you want, but after 3 or 4, things get nasty to keep straight in your head.

Comment: @nectar `$result_array[0]['userId']` to be correct, but most likely you'll never address array variables like this because arrays intended to be iterated using `foreach()` operator

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT a.userId, b.name, b.dob FROM tbltree a INNER JOIN tblprofile b ON a.userId = b.userId WHERE a.superId ='$uid' LIMIT 1";
```

Then we use mysql_fetch-assoc to collect a row

```
if(false != ($resource = mysql_query($sql)))
{
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
    // Dont use a while here as we only want to iterate 1 row.
}

echo $result['name'];
```

Also added "LIMIT 1" to your query